# Row_number function and variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I have a problem placing the `ROW_NUMBER` onto the right spot while I am using variables in my query.

I want to create a lookup function by checking every record from the first till the last record. There's something I'm not doing right with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Any tips?

```
/* DECLARATION */
...
/* LOOKUP */
SET @MAXID = (SELECT COUNT(ContractNr) FROM SenoOud.dbo.Financieel)
SET @COUNTER = 1
WHILE @COUNTER < @MAXID
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @ROWNUM = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ContractNr) AS 'CNUM',
                @IGAS = [Factuur CO/LPG], 
                @IBRAND = [Factuur Brand], 
                @IOVERIG = [Factuur Overig],
        FROM SenOoud.dbo.Financieel
        WHERE @ROWNUM = @COUNTER
/* INSERTION */
...
```

Comment: You may want to have look at SQL cursors. I think they'll be a better solution than this :)

Comment: You may want to have a look at SQL's Set based approach to avoid looping and cursor where possible, for example over here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/03/30/procedural-versus-set-based-sql.aspx :)

Comment: Why do you need this? There is probably a better solution for the broader problem using a set based approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach will work best

```
SELECT Row_number()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY ContractNr) AS RNUM,
       [Factuur CO/LPG],
       [Factuur Brand],
       [Factuur Overig]
INTO   #TEMP
FROM   SenOoud.dbo.Financieel


SET @MAXID = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @COUNTER = 1
WHILE @COUNTER < @MAXID
  BEGIN
      SELECT top 1 @ROWNUM =RNUM,
             @IGAS = [Factuur CO/LPG],
             @IBRAND = [Factuur Brand],
             @IOVERIG = [Factuur Overig]
      FROM   #TEMP
      WHERE  RNUM = @COUNTER

      SET @COUNTER=@COUNTER + 1
END
```

I have added top 1 just in case

Comment: Agreed. Like a charm, thank you very much, both.
EDIT: Just need to create an alias for the #TEMP section

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @IGAS = [Factuur CO/LPG],
       @IBRAND = [Factuur Brand],
       @IOVERIG = [Factuur Overig]
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY ContractNr) AS ROWNUM,
               [Factuur CO/LPG],
               [Factuur Brand],
               [Factuur Overig]
        FROM   SenOoud.dbo.Financieel) A
WHERE  ROWNUM = @COUNTER
```

If you still get error try this same thing i have done with sample data

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
  (
     col1 VARCHAR(50),
     col2 VARCHAR(50),
     col3 VARCHAR(50)
  )

SELECT *
FROM   #temp

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES      ('1','A319','zvxfsdg'),
            ('2','efg','ddfgdfg'),
            ('3','xdfg','ddfgxfgdfg')

SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY col1) AS ROWNUM,
               col1,
               col2,
               col3
        FROM   #temp) A
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured the subquery now as well, but it does give me an incorrect syntax. Yours gives me an incorrect syntax near 'A'

Comment: Check now previously there s a mistake

Comment: @IvanM Am not getting any error check now i have added sample code